# Did Solidity ever release a new feature in a version that was rolled back in later versions?

Tags: solidity

The question title is pretty self-explanatory. I'm wondering if that ever happened. And if so, what were those features and which were the Solidity versions where they were released/rolled back?

Comment: I think there are not many things which have been really removed. Only two things come to my mind: `now` and `years`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's not rare at all. Almost every breaking version removes something old and deprecated. You can easily find them in the [changelog](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md). Often the goal is to make the language stricter and introduce extra checks. Sometimes these removals are things that turned out not to be very useful.

Here's a selection that only includes stuff that could be reasonably be considered useful by someone. There were also unintentional "features" like e.g. the fact that you could include leading zeros in `bytesXX` types until 0.7.6 (e.g. `bytes007` was valid) or have a useless variable of library type until 0.7.4. I also skipped removal of compiler options, parts of AST output, etc.

- 0.8.0

> - General: Remove global functions `log0`, `log1`, `log2`, `log3` and `log4`.
> - Scanner: Remove support for the `\b`, `\f`, and `\v` escape sequences.
> - Type System: Disallow enums with more than 256 members.
> - Type System: Disallow the `byte` type. It was an alias to `bytes1`.
> - Type System: Explicit conversions between two types are disallowed if it changes more than one of sign, width or kind at the same time.

- 0.7.0

> - Parser: Remove the `finney` and `szabo` denominations.
> - Parser: Remove the identifier `now` (replaced by `block.timestamp`).
> - Type Checker: Disallow structs and arrays in memory or calldata if they contain nested mappings.
> - Inline Assembly: Disallow `.` in user-defined function and variable names.
> - Yul: Disallow consecutive and trailing dots in identifiers. Leading dots were already disallowed.
> - Yul: Disallow EVM instruction `pc()`.

- 0.6.2

> - LLL: The LLL compiler has been removed.

- 0.5.10

> - Yul / Inline Assembly Parser: Disallow trailing commas in function call arguments.

- 0.5.0

> - General: Disallow declaring empty structs.
> - General: Disallow raw `callcode`.
> - General: Disallow `var` keyword.
> - General: Disallow `sha3` and `suicide` aliases.
> - General: Disallow the `throw` statement.
> - General: Disallow the `years` unit denomination.
> - General: Disallow combining hex numbers with unit denominations (e.g. `0x1e wei`).
> - Parser: Disallow trailing dots that are not followed by a number.
> - Parser: Disallow uppercase X in hex number literals
> - Type Checker: Disallow assignments between tuples with different numbers of components.
> - Type Checker: Disallow arithmetic operations for boolean variables.
> - Type Checker: Disallow calling base constructors without parentheses.
> - Type Checker: Disallow conversions between `bytesX` and `uintY` of different size.
> - Type Checker: Disallow conversions between unrelated contract types.
> - Type Checker: Disallow empty return statements for functions with one or more return values.
> - Type Checker: Disallow empty tuple components.
> - Type Checker: Disallow multi-variable declarations with mismatching number of values.
> - Type Checker: Disallow calling constructor with wrong argument count.
> - Type Checker: Disallow uninitialized storage variables.
> - Type Checker: Only accept a single bytes type for `.call()` (and family), `keccak256()`, `sha256()` and `ripemd160()`.
> - Type Checker: Address members are not included in contract types anymore. An explicit conversion is now required before invoking an `address` member from a contract.
> - Type Checker: Disallow "loose assembly" syntax entirely. This means that jump labels, jumps and non-functional instructions cannot be used anymore.
> - Type System: Disallow explicit and implicit conversions from decimal literals to `bytesXX` types.
> - Type System: Disallow explicit and implicit conversions from hex literals to `bytesXX` types of different size.
> - Syntax Checker: Named return values in function types are an error.
> - Syntax Checker: Disallow unary `+`.

If you're interested in what might be removed in the future, most of that stuff is labeled as a [`breaking change` in the bug tracker](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22breaking+change+%3Awarning%3A%22+):

- [Drop support for ancient EVM versions, i.e. for homestead #12246](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/12246)
- [Remove support for the catch all (*) in the using statement #11882](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11882)
- [Reconsider operators on ContractType #11700](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11700)
- [Remove abi.encodePacked #11593](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11593)
- [Disallow absolute import paths (path spec v3) #11410](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11410)
- [Remove the ripemd160 builtin #9358](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/9358)
- [Deprecate gasleft() native method (GAS opcode) #8363](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/8363)

The fact that there's an issue for it of course does not mean it will actually be removed, just that it's being considered.